# no attribute 'wrap_socket' in python 2.7 beutifulsoup in windows

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

When i run this script gives error 'wrap_socket' missing

try to install ssl using pip command but every time failed

```
import pickle, pdb, traceback
from pymongo import MongoClient
import urllib2, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pprint
import socket, ssl
```

**this is my class**

```
class AvvoQA(object):
    def _init_(self):
        self.client=MongoClient('localhost',27017)
        self.db=self.client.local
        self.collection=self.db.awo
```

**this is database insert code**

```
    def ins(self,awo):
        client=MongoClient('localhost',27017)
        db=client.local
        collection=db.awo
        collection.insert(awo)
```

**This is main function**

```
    def awoMain(self):
        article_list = []
        link = 'https://www.avvo.com/topics/green-cards/advice?question=1'
        findFile = urllib2.urlopen(link)
        findHtml = findFile.read()
        findFile.close()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(findHtml, "lxml")
        que = soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class' : 'card topic-advice-question-card'})
        for div in que:
            try:
                awo = {}
                awo['question'] = div.findAll('a',attrs={'class':'block-link'})['href']
                record['desc_link'] = div.find('a')['href']
                record = self.getAns(record)
                pprint.pprint(awo)
            except:
                print
                print "This articles faces issue "
                print traceback.format_exc()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    AvvoQA().awoMain()
```

**Error shown**

```
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 803, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 755, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 1156, in connect
    self.sock = ssl.wrap_socket(sock, self.key_file, self.cert_file)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'wrap_socket'
```

Comment: Please edit the question to include the full stacktrace, we would then hopefully see where the error is being reported.

Comment: @MartinEvans please check it

Comment: `ssl` was added to Python 2.6 so there would be no need to pip install it in Python 2.7. Perhaps you have managed to install a different `ssl` module? Try `pip list`, `ssl` should not be listed. Also in Python try `print ssl.wrap_socket` which should show something like `<function wrap_socket at 0x000000000C7DD518>`

Comment: when i try to install ssl its give error                                          
 
  `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'OPENSSL_VERSION'`

Comment: `ssl` is already installed by default in Python 2.6 onwards. No need to install it.

Comment: @MartinEvans  yes i kown ssl is by default in python 2.7 but when i `import ssl` it also give ssl error `Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.`

Comment: @Aasif - Please post the _full_ stacktrace, not just the last few lines.